# Why JGroups channel send message failed?

Tags: java, jgroups

I'm using JGroups as my group communication tool in my project, And im studing how to use jgroups.
When i run this demo with default udp.xml configuration, creating two channels called A and B, i found that those two channels didnt become a group and even channel A itself cannot send message to it's own! Why?

By the way, i run some code earlier and it's ok. But today it's failed.

```java
import org.jgroups.JChannel;
import org.jgroups.Message;
import org.jgroups.blocks.*;
import org.jgroups.util.RspList;
import org.jgroups.util.Util;

public class DispatchWithBuildingBlocksTest implements RequestHandler {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
            new DispatchWithBuildingBlocksTest().startInMessage();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public void startInMessage() throws Exception {

        JChannel channelA = new JChannel().name("channelA");
        JChannel channelB = new JChannel().name("channelB");

        MessageDispatcher dispA = new MessageDispatcher(channelA, this);
        MessageDispatcher dispB = new MessageDispatcher(channelB, this);

        channelA.connect("test group");
        channelB.connect("test group");

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            Util.sleep(100);
            System.out.println("Casting message #" + i);
            byte[] payload = ("number #" + i).getBytes();
            RspList list = dispA.castMessage(null, payload, 0, payload.length, RequestOptions.SYNC());
            System.out.println("Responses: \n" + list);
        }

        Util.close(dispA, dispB, channelA, channelB);
    }

    @Override
    public Object handle(Message message) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("handle():" + message);
        return "Success!";
    }
}
```

The result i got:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
GMS: address=channelA, cluster=test group, physical address=192.168.120.242:59299
-------------------------------------------------------------------

-------------------------------------------------------------------
GMS: address=channelB, cluster=test group, physical address=192.168.120.242:50818
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Casting message #0
Responses: 
[channelA: received=false, suspected=false]

Casting message #1
Responses: 
[channelA: received=false, suspected=false]

Casting message #2
Responses: 
[channelA: received=false, suspected=false]

Casting message #3
Responses: 
[channelA: received=false, suspected=false]

Casting message #4
Responses: 
[channelA: received=false, suspected=false]

Casting message #5
Responses: 
[channelA: received=false, suspected=false]

Casting message #6
Responses: 
[channelA: received=false, suspected=false]

Casting message #7

Process finished with exit code 130 (interrupted by signal 2: SIGINT)
```

I canceled when it counts to 7 because i thought it would be the same by 10.

Please help me, Thanks!

Comment: I have solved this problem. It's because i had two dependencies in maven of JGroups, one is JGroups and another is a program which includes JGroups of different version. I kept one and delete another, problem solved ...

Comment: But im still confused of those two dependencies. One of them is in package org.jgroups and another is in package com.xxx.xxx.jgroups. Why did they conflict? Maybe there was something i didnt know about what maven did.